# Checking if CSS Attribute Selectors values match, without hard-coding the actual value

Tags: css

The basline question:

```
/* can this: */
x[attr="value1"] ~ y[attr="value1"],
x[attr="value2"] ~ y[attr="value2"],
x[attr="value3"] ~ y[attr="value3"] {
    ...
}

/* be written in some waylike this: (?) */
x[attr="*"] ~ y[attr="*"] {
    ...
}

/* practically check if the attribute values are the same, without hard-coding every possible value */
/* apply only if value of y[attr] matches the value of x[attr], dynamically */
/* something like a **if-previous-attribute-value-matches-my-own-attribute-value check** */
```

---

I am well aware that this check can be done easily with JS ('ve done may time to this day).
The point of the exercise is to do it with only CSS (and it works just fine).

But it bloats both the markup and the CSS footprint, and I would like to find out if something like a **if-previous-attribute-value-matches-my-own-attribute-value check** can be achieved in CSS, without having to hard-code the value.

---

This is an exercise I've been doing for quite some time: 
I've been using checkboxes and CSS attribute selectors to create some **CSS-only components** 
(using the :checked state - to mimic a click/toggle event, and sibling selectors - to apply changes to the component based on said :checked state).

```
<form class="cssTabs">

    <input class="cssTabs-btn" name="cssTabs-btn" type="radio" data-tabs-id="1" checked="checked" />
    <input class="cssTabs-btn" name="cssTabs-btn" type="radio" data-tabs-id="2"/>
    <input class="cssTabs-btn" name="cssTabs-btn" type="radio" data-tabs-id="3"/>

    <div class="cssTabs-labelGroup">
        <div class="cssTabs-btnLabel" data-tabs-id="1">Button 1</div>
        <div class="cssTabs-btnLabel" data-tabs-id="2">Button 2</div>
        <div class="cssTabs-btnLabel" data-tabs-id="3">Button 3</div>
    </div>

    <div class="cssTabs-contentGroup">
        <div class="cssTabs-content" data-tabs-id="1"> Content 1 </div>
        <div class="cssTabs-content" data-tabs-id="2"> Content 2 </div>
        <div class="cssTabs-content" data-tabs-id="3"> Content 3 </div>
    </div>

</form>
```

The 'problem' is, that the markup for certain components does not allow for the corresponding checkbox to be the sibling of the coresponding 'element-to-affect':

```
.cssTabs-btn:checked  ~ .cssTabs-btnLabel { ... }
```

And so, something like data-attributes needs to be used, to differentiate between them.

```
.cssTabs-btn[data-tabs-id="1"]:checked  ~ .cssTabs-labelGroup .cssTabs-btnLabel[data-tabs-id="1"],
.cssTabs-btn[data-tabs-id="2"]:checked  ~ .cssTabs-labelGroup .cssTabs-btnLabel[data-tabs-id="2"],
.cssTabs-btn[data-tabs-id="3"]:checked  ~ .cssTabs-labelGroup .cssTabs-btnLabel[data-tabs-id="3"] { 
    ... 
}
```

As can be seen, this can **bloat the markup**, but more importantly **increase the CSS parsing footprint (when layouts/reflows occur)**. 
*And it is also not auto-adaptable to the number of existing 'scenarios'*

---

So, is something such as a dynamic **if-previous-attribute-value-matches-my-own-attribute-value check** possible in any orthodox/hacky way, in CSS ? :)

Comment: Just curious. `.cssTabs-btn:checked  ~ .cssTabs-labelGroup .cssTabs-btnLabel` won't work for your use-case?

Comment: No, as if any checkbox is checked, it would apply true for all 3 btnLabel items. This is why a differentiator is required for each of them. That is simply an example through an use case, to provide a 'real-world' example of where such a selector/resolve could be useful.